# Passing a complex data vs passing its property

Tags: c#, properties

I know this is a basic question but I kind of wanted to know some key details in their differences and how does it affects performance !

Below is a C# example.

Suppose I have a Person class with properties like

```
public class Person 
{
    int PersonIds{get;set;}
    string Name{get;set;}
    ...
    ... 
}
```

and I have defined somewhere

```
List<Person> myFamily; // I later initialize to contail all my family members.
```

Now I have 2 functions `fun1` and `fun2`

```
List<Person> fun1(List<Person> myFamily)
 {
    ... // here some logic occurs and I get some less no. of Person in return list.
    ...
 }
```

somewhere else

```
List<Person> selectedPersons = fun1(myFamily);
```

VS

```
 List<int> fun2(List<int> myFamilyPersonIds)
 {
    ... // Here same logic occurs as fun1 but it only needs personID to perform it.
    ...
 }
```

somewhere else

```
 List<int> selectedPersonIds = fun2(myFamilyPersonIds);
 List<Person> selectedPersons = myFamily.where(a=>selectedPersonIds.contains(a.PersonId));
```

I want to know in what ways does this effect the performance.

Tips and suggestions are also welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to know the correct answer is to use a tool to *profile* the code, and see where your program is really spending it's time. Before this, you're just doing guess-work and pre-mature optimization.

However, assuming you already have these objects constructed, I tend to prefer the `fun1()` option. This is because it's passing around references to the *same* objects in memory. The `fun2()` option needs to make copies of the integer IDs. As a reference is the same size as an integer, I'd expect copying integers to be about the same amount of work as copying references. That part is a wash.

However, by staying with references you can save the later step of finding the whole object based on the ID. That should simplify your code, making it easier to read and maintain, and save work for the computer (improve performance), too.

Also, imagine for a moment that your property were something larger than an integer... say, a string. In this case, passing the object could be a *huge* performance win. But again, what I expect is just a naive guess without results from a real profiling tool.

Comment: hmm, till now I thought that fun2 will be bit lesser as I only need to pass 1 property instead of whole class !

Comment: When it "passes the whole class" it's really just passing an address in memory where that object lives aka a pointer

Comment: Ya I agree, good I will now raise this point to my senior at work tomorrow, he made me change all my code to use a property instead of a whole list in argument. Thanks.

Comment: @Joel : thanks for the answer.. now I understand the answer and reason behind it. Now I will be able to distinguish better, where to use fun1 and where to use fun2 .